# Extending method with generic obeservable as return type

Tags: rxjs5, typescript1.8, angular2-testing

rxjs: 5.0.0-beta.2
Typescript: 1.8
Angular2: beta-9

I'm trying to mock a http service class but run into problems when extending the class as described in angular 2 docs.

Seems like you can't override a method that returns an typed observable? What am I missing?

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {IQuery} from "../Query";
import {Http} from "angular2/http";

export interface IQuery<TResult> {        
}

export class A {
    public test = <T>(q: IQuery<T>): Observable<T> => {
        var queryName = this.getName(query);
        var url = `api/query/${queryName}`;
        return this.httpPost<TResult>(url, query);
    };
}

export class AMock extends A {
    public test = <T>(q: IQuery<T>): Observable<T> => {
        return mockObservable;
    };
}

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2415  Class 'AMock' incorrectly extends base class 'A'.
  Types of property 'test' are incompatible.
    Type '<T>(q: IQuery<T>) => Observable<T>' is not assignable to type '<T>(q: IQuery<T>) => Observable<T>'.
      Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'.
        Property 'source' is protected but type 'Observable<T>' is not a class derived from 'Observable<T>'.    TypeScript Virtual Projects
```

Works if return type is T but not `observable<T>`.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you produce a single file example that defines `Iq` and has the imports for Rx? The imports and/or types could be part of it.

Comment: You might also want to upgrade to beta6 if that's possible.

Comment: Updated with more code. I tested beta-6 with new angular 2 rc-1 but ran in to other problems. The error/problem was still present so I don't think it is solved by rxjs beta-6

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is in the code you pointed out. Maybe in the imports in actual code or something.

The following code compiles fine in typeScript ^1.8.10:

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

export interface IQuery<TResult> {        
}

export class A {
    public test = <T>(q: IQuery<T>): Observable<T> => {
        return null;
    };
}

export class AMock extends A {
    public test = <T>(q: IQuery<T>): Observable<T> => {
        return null;
    };
}
```

And I can compile it using the latest Angular2 quick start plunker as well (the first plunker link in [Quick Start Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)).

Check the `app/main.ts` file in:

http://plnkr.co/edit/cedJly52HvfIoS2fpzkY?p=preview

(Note: When the compilation fails, the output stays at "Loading..." forever, so that's how you can verify it compiled)